# In Android, how to start an activity of application B when user click on notification from application A?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, android-context

I have searched online for answer, but all I got was how to start an activity inside application A when clicking on A's notification. The problem is, to start activities of B, I will need the Context of B to pass it to the PendingIntent for the notification of A, but I cannot get the Context of B in A.

Is there any way to do so, or am I supposed to do something else to start app B other than use PendingIntent.getActivity() method?

Comment: Two things.  1) Post the code where you are issuing the pending intent. 2) Post the manifest part that describes how these activities should be addressed.

Comment: Then someone will quickly solve this.

Comment: Also user1524355 is not very compelling name.

Comment: Well, the name was auto-generated for me I guess. I'll change it later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the context of B to pass to the pending intent, just an intent pointing to the second activity.

If for some odd reason this is not working(though it should), you could just have your notification fire to a `BraodcastReceiver` and start the activity there, but like i said this should NOT be required.

```
Intent secondActivity = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);

PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   context, 
   0, // or you can use some unique id
   secondActivity, 
   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Correct.  There is absolutely no need to get any other context then the one you have.

Comment: How do I create a PendingIntent to start an activity without the context? The PendingIntent.getActivity (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags) takes the context as a parameter.

Comment: yes, just use w/e context you have currently, your activities, applications w/e. You need A context, just not the specific context of the second activity.

Comment: @jug6ernaut For the intent, should I use Intent.makeMainActivity() to create it?